# Java 8 file read method

Tags: java, parsing

I have a method which extracts `filedata` and converts it into a `String` array:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import org.apache.james.mime4j.message.BodyPart;
import org.apache.james.mime4j.message.Message;
import org.apache.james.mime4j.message.Multipart;
import org.apache.james.mime4j.message.TextBody;

protected String[] extractLedesText(byte[] fileData) {
    // Remove the BOM if present
    byte[] array = { (byte) 0xEF, (byte) 0xBB, (byte) 0xBF };
    byte[] data =  { fileData[0], fileData[1], fileData[2] };
    if (fileData.length > 3 && Arrays.equals(data, array)) {
        fileData = ArrayUtils.subarray(fileData, 3, fileData.length-1);            
    }

    String ledes = new String(fileData);
    if (ledes.startsWith("MIME")) {

        try {
            ledes = null;
            Message signed = new Message(new ByteArrayInputStream(fileData));
            for (BodyPart part : ((Multipart) signed.getBody()).getBodyParts()) {
                if (part.getMimeType().equalsIgnoreCase("text/plain")) {
                    TextBody tb = (TextBody) part.getBody();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    tb.writeTo(baos);
                    return extractLedesText(baos.toByteArray());
                }
            }
            throw new BaseApplicationException(
                    "No MIME part found with MIME type of 'text/plain' while parsing submitted invoice file.");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new BaseApplicationException(ioe);
        }
    } else {
        return ledes.split("\\[]");
    }

}
```

For example, below is the leads file:

> ```
> LEDES98BI V2[]
> INVOICE_DATE|INVOICE_NUMBER|CLIENT_ID|LAW_FIRM_MATTER_ID|INVOICE_TOTAL[]
> 20150301|INV-Error_Test1|160|LF_MAT_1221|22[]
> 20150301|INV-Error_Test1|160|LF_MAT_1221|22[]
> 20150301|INV-Error_Test1|160|LF_MAT_1221|22[]
> ```

The `extractLedesText` method converts the above file data to string array of lines.

We recently upgraded to Java 8 and am wondering whether this method can be optimized further.

Comment: Is [this](https://james.apache.org/mime4j/apidocs/org/apache/james/mime4j/message/Message.html) the Javadoc for the `Message` class? And the other [Javadocs](https://james.apache.org/mime4j/apidocs/index.html)...

Comment: updated the question with the imports for Message and other classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `extractLedesText()` is trying to do three things:

1. Strip away any [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) from `fileData`.
2. If this is a MIME message, extract only the [`TextBody`](https://james.apache.org/mime4j/apidocs/org/apache/james/mime4j/message/TextBody.html) part and pass that recursively into this method again.
3. Else just do a `split("\\[]")` to get our desired `String[]` array.

So...

## Data massaging

You can use a helper method to achieve this:

```
private static byte[] filterBOM(byte[] fileData) {
    if (fileData.length < 3) {
        return fileData;
    }
    final byte[] array = { (byte) 0xEF, (byte) 0xBB, (byte) 0xBF };
    final byte[] data =  { fileData[0], fileData[1], fileData[2] };
    return fileData.length > 3 && Arrays.equals(data, array) ? 
        Arrays.copyRangeOf(fileData, 3, fileData.length) : fileData;
}
```

I think it may be better to do a `fileData.length < 3` check *before* you construct your `data` array. Also, I am using the `Arrays` utility class instead of `ArrayUtils` to copy part of the array.

## Extracting the `TextBody` from a MIME message

You can make use of `try-with-resources` for both your `ByteArrayInputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream` instances, and I suppose this is where we can employ a bit of Stream trickery...

```
private static byte[] getTextBody(final String ledes) {
    final TextBody tb;
    try (final InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(ledes.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
        tb = ((Multipart) new Message(input).getBody()).getBodyParts().stream()
                .filter(part -> part.getMimeType().equalsIgnoreCase("text/plain"))
                .findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new BaseApplicationException(
                    "No MIME part found with MIME type of 'text/plain' while parsing submitted invoice file."))
                .getBody();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new BaseApplicationException(e);
    }
    try (final ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        tb.writeTo(output);
        return output.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new BaseApplicationException(e);
    }
}
```

We stream on the `List` from [`getBodyParts()`](https://james.apache.org/mime4j/apidocs/org/apache/james/mime4j/message/Multipart.html#getBodyParts%28%29), filtering those where their MIME type is `"text/plain"` and then look for the first matching `BodyPart`. If there isn't any, we call `orElseThrow()` with a `new BaseApplicationException(...)`, otherwise we will `getBody()` and `writeTo()` your `ByteArrayOutputStream`. The output of this method is a `byte[]` array if there are no thrown `Exception`s.

## Putting it all together

```
protected String[] extractLedesText(byte[] fileData) {
    final String ledes = new String(filterBOM(fileData));
    return ledes.startsWith("MIME") ? extractLedesText(getTextBody(ledes)) : ledes.split("\\[]");
}
```